# Kusto - Get average of timestamp

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, windows-virtual-desktop

I have the logs of WVD. I want to get the average duration of the connections in one day. So far I got this code

```
datatable(Timestamp:datetime, User:string, State:string)
[ 
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:02:02.527 AM), 'user1', 'Started', , 
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:02:09.244 AM), 'user1', 'Connected', 
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:14:21.156 AM), 'user1', 'Completed', 
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:29:27.195 AM), 'user1', 'Started', 
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:29:30.544 AM), 'user1', 'Connected', 
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:45:35.438 AM), 'user1', 'Completed', 
]
| where State == "Started" or State == "Completed"
| where datetime_part("dayOfYear",TimeGenerated) == datetime_part("dayOfYear",todatetime('2020-06-25 01:02:03.7654321'))
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by State, UserName
| order by UserName asc, TimeGenerated asc 
| extend duration = iff(UserName == prev(UserName), TimeGenerated - prev(TimeGenerated), 0s)
| summarize avg(duration) by UserName, State
| where State == "Completed"
```

I want to get the avg time between all the completed - started time of each user and each connection

Thanks!

Comment: it may help if you explain how you define the beginning and the end of a `connection`, and provide a sample data set (using the `datatable` operator) that helps demonstrate the problem you're trying to solve - i.e. includes the input, expected matching output, and brief description of the logic that transforms the input into the output

Comment: Add it! thanks for the observation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
datatable(Timestamp:datetime, User:string, State:string)
[ 
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:02:02.527 AM), 'user1', 'Started', 
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:02:09.244 AM), 'user1', 'Connected', 
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:14:21.156 AM), 'user1', 'Completed', 
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:29:27.195 AM), 'user1', 'Started', 
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:29:30.544 AM), 'user1', 'Connected', 
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:45:35.438 AM), 'user1', 'Completed', 
]
| where State == "Started" or State == "Completed"
| where startofday(Timestamp) == datetime(2019-10-23)
| order by User asc, Timestamp asc 
| extend duration = iff(User == prev(User) and State == 'Completed' and prev(State) == "Started", Timestamp - prev(Timestamp), timespan(null))
| where isnotnull(duration)
| summarize avg(duration) by User // you can remove the 'by User' if you don't need it. it wasn't completely clear from your question
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. Some changes to adapt to the original table. :)

Comment: Small change on the filter: | where duration != "00:00:00"